# Start and end date of promotion on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, promotion-code

I can set the start date and end date about my promotion on Google Play Console as you guys know. But, I don’t know exactly what it means.

1. Promotion code could be “input” only this period. And the users who use promotion code, can enjoy its product permanently.
2. The users who use promotion code, can enjoy its product only this period.

Which one is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's number 1. Once the code has been redeemed, the user can use the app forever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :D